# Using Multiples in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to teach myself C and have only done a few things in CodeAcademy so far. I'm pretty lacking when it comes to loops in my current online course. Let's say I wanted to use a loop to make the first 5 multiples of 1 through 10 like below.

```html
Number  1st     2nd     3rd     4th     5th
1       1       2       3       4       5
2       2       4       6       8       10
3       3       6       9       12      15
4       4       8       12      16      20
5       5       10      15      20      25
6       6       12      18      24      30
7       7       14      21      28      35
8       8       16      24      32      40
9       9       18      27      36      45
10      10      20      30      40      50
```

I'm drawing a blank on how I would use loop nesting or even a single loop to do the above. Anyone have any advice on where to start, I'm not understanding this I guess.

Comment: I'm just here to warn that most people won't be sympathetic to your question because there are many online resources to help understanding loops already. Stack Overflow answerers usually prefer to help with novel questions.

Comment: Multiple nested loops can sometimes get out of hand. There is usually a better-looking solution.

Comment: Please read this tutorial for beginners: http://beginnersbook.com/2014/01/c-for-loop/

Comment: Okay, so what part are you having trouble with? What programs have you written so far? Do you understand the for loop syntax? In your own words, why do you think a loop is appropriate for solving the problem? (It is, but you have to clearly understand your own thoughts in order to program.) In your own words, what is supposed to happen each time through the loop? Where do you want to begin and end looping? Then you write the code.

Comment: I've only done the basics with printf, scanf, if statements, etc. I really just need a better understanding of C fundamentals and I'm pretty lost on loops.

Comment: the C language only has ~7 statements (though there are lots of nuances). Suggest learning the `for()` statement for your looping

Answer (score 1):

A big part of programming is about breaking larger problems into smaller problems.

If the problem of making this table is too much for you, then break the problem into pieces. e.g.

- Write a function that can print the header
- Write a function capable of printing one line of the table
- Write a program that uses those two functions to print the whole table

Answer (score 0):

see [printf description](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char *field_name[] = {"Number", "1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", "5th" };
    int field_size = 10;
    int num_of_fields = 6;
    int number_max = 10;

    //print field_name
    for(int i = 0; i < num_of_fields; ++i)
        printf("%-*s", field_size, field_name[i]);
    puts("");
    //print numbers
    for(int n = 1; n <= number_max; ++n){
        printf("%-*d", field_size, n);
        for(int i = 1; i < num_of_fields; ++i)
            printf("%-*d", field_size, n * i);
        puts("");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, I wasn't aware that I could of avoided a nested loop for this...

On a side note, do you know any better sites to learn C other than CodeAcademy?

Comment: _I would use loop nesting_

Comment: It possible doesn't use nested loop. but Such a trick does not make sense.

Comment: the 'magic' numbers: 6, 10,10 would probably be better defined via an `enum` statement or `#define` statements.

Comment: I tried to remove the downvote, but the system would not let me